# SQL statement not working SELECT 1064 Error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, select

My SQL statement doesn't work...

Here is my variable:

```
$email="test@test.com";
```

These statements doesn't work :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = $email";
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = ' . $email;
```

1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@test.com' at line 1

But if I use a string instead of the variable, it works:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = 'test@test.com'";
```

What's wrong with my statement?
Thanks!

Comment: You should google SQL Injection Attacks, and Prepared Statements

Comment: @Steve, and you downvoted it for this?

Comment: @Steve, sorry then. I see a lot of downvotes and don't really understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please escape strings in mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = $email"; 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = ' . $email;
```

This should work

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = '$email'";
```

Answer (score 0):

table is a keyword, so can write like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE email='$email'";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
    $query =$this->db->get($this->user);

  //$sql = "SELECT * FROM  user WHERE email = '$email'"; 
if($query->num_rows == 1)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

}
}